# Salesforce Lightning Flow Builder lookup Error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to build a Flow to create records for contacts. I am going to create a button off of Accounts on the related list of Contacts. 
Step 2 is where I am having an issue

1.) I created a Get Records - which gets the ID of accounts. 
2.) I created a Screen: 
    I have a lookup field that I want to be defaulted to the parent.

I have the FieldAPIName as AccountID which is a Varialble I created that is stored from Step 1. 
Label : Entity Name
Object API Name : Account

When I run the program I get the following error: 
Looks like you don't have access to this field, or the object or field API name is not valid on this Lookup component. Contact your Salesforce admin for help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your source object is Contact and the field is AccountId.